# alert() is not working on PHP , instead getting printed on console

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to show an alert but its not working dont know what I'm missing please point out :

```
//my.php

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $message = "Mail sent.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";           
} 
else {
    echo json_encode(['success'=>false]); 
}
```

The above supposed to show a alert on browser but its not showing anything at all. But it is getting printed on console   anyone know what is wrong here ?

**UPDATE**

```
//myPhpCall: 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myForm").on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmail.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("Mail sent"); // not getting called

                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This `<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>` may be returning from the server, but is not being executed, because there is nothing triggering it... are you reloading the hole page, or getting the server return like a call to it? I think you could add to what ever function or event calling the PHP from the server the `alert()` (user side) the `$message` the server is returning...

Comment: Are you using `jQuery` to submit your form?

Comment: @julekgwa yes ,  let me try your way

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are doing some kind of [output escaping](https://www.inanimatt.com/php-output-escaping.html) somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

Just return the results to jQuery and alert from there.

```
// if mail was sent
echo json_encode(["success" => true]);
```

Then in your jQuery in your `ajax`

```
var res = $.parseJSON(data);
if (res.success == true) {
    alert("Mail sent");
}else {
//code here
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post('sendmail.php', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(data){
      var res = $.parseJSON(data);
      if (res.result == true) {
          alert('Mail sent');
      }else if(res.result == false) {
          alert('Mail not sent');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: @julegwa seems like i'm already trying what you suggested but its not getting being called , correct me if i'm wrong . please check the updated question

Comment: @remyboys I have tested your code and it's working on my side. I f you are still having a problem you can use the updated code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following in your my.php -

```
<?php
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { $message = "Mail sent.";
?>
 <script type='text/javascript'>alert(<?php echo $message ?> );</script>

<?php } else { echo json_encode(['success'=>false]); }
?>
```